# Buddypress cover photo upload area missing

Tags: wordpress, upload, photo, buddypress, cover

after updating Buddypress to 2.4.3 (Wordpress is 4.2.6) I found out that they added Profile cover photo into Buddypress core. Thing is that in "Change Cover Image" tab in profile page there is no upload area.

Does anybody have a clue, what might be wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you checked if it's enabled in 'Screen options' at the top of your page when you edit the profile?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks but I meant it is not displayed in front end. I guess you are talking about admin area, right?

Comment: @Pupik - I'm having the same issue. Did you find a way to resolve this?